# File upload using Dropzone but it doesn't upload to the folder

Tags: javascript, python, dropzone.js

Here is my code. It adds to the database but it doesn't upload to the folder. I don't know where to put the path foldername wherein the file should be uploaded and I don't know how to retrieve the filename of the file so I could add it to the database. The only thing that is uploading to the database is the ObjectId which is automatically given by MongoDB.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'UploadImages',
        previewsContainer: "#dropzone-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 20,
        init: function() {
            var cd;
            this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                $('.dz-progress').hide();
                $('.dz-size').hide();
                $('.dz-error-mark').hide();
                console.log(response);
                console.log(file);
                cd = response;
            });
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<a href=\"#\">Remove file</a>");
                var _this = this;
                removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    _this.removeFile(file);
                    var name = "largeFileName=" + cd.pi.largePicPath + "&smallFileName=" + cd.pi.smallPicPath;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'DeleteImage',
                        data: name,
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                });
                file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="UploadImages" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

**Python**

```
@view_config(route_name='upload', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
    def upload(self):
        # Only allow post data 
        if self.request.method != 'POST': 
            return {'success' : False, 'error' : True, 'message' : 'Post method is only allow'}        
        user = Dropzone(
            firstname = self.request.POST.get('firstname'))
        user.save()

        return ['sample']
```

Comment: Fixed: I used the file upload in the documentation of the Pyramid

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I followed the file upload in the documentation of the Pyramid